# Erlang Hot Code loading fails to keep state

Tags: erlang

I'm a beginner at erlang programming. To understand hot code loading better, I used the example from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29#Hot_code_loading_and_modules) (I added responses to the sending Pid for debugging):

```
%% A process whose only job is to keep a counter.
  %% First version
  -module(counter).
  -export([start/0, codeswitch/2]).

  start() -> loop(0).

  loop(Sum) ->
    receive
       {increment, Count} ->
          loop(Sum+Count);
        %% modified code, which will be loaded:
        % reset -> 
        %     loop(0);
       {counter, Pid} ->
          Pid ! {counter, Sum},
          loop(Sum);
        {code_switch, Pid} ->
          Pid ! {switch, Sum},
          ?MODULE:codeswitch(Pid, Sum)
          % Force the use of 'codeswitch/2' from the latest MODULE version
    end.

  codeswitch(FromPid, Sum) -> 
      FromPid ! {switched, Sum},
      loop(Sum).
```

All is good. I can load the module via `c(counter).` in the shell, spawn a new process via `Pid = spawn(fun counter:start/0).` and send messages to the spawned process. When I now add a new pattern to the receive expression `reset -> loop(0)` and reload the code via `c(counter).`, everything works as expected, new code is loaded, `Sum` keeps its incremented value etc.

But when I send the `{code_switch, self()}` message, `Sum` gets reset to 0 when `loop(Sum)` is called (`FromPid ! {switched, Sum}` in the call to `FromPid ! {switched, Sum}` still returns correct state).

What am I missing, why does my state go away after the first call to an codeswitched function?

Thanks for your help!

```
| 18 | Pid ! {counter, self()}.
{counter,<0.49.0>}
| 19 | flush().
Shell got {counter,6}
ok
| 20 | Pid ! {code_switch, self()}.
{code_switch,<0.49.0>}
| 21 | flush().
Shell got {switch,6}
Shell got {switched,6}
ok
| 22 | Pid ! {counter, self()}.
{counter,<0.49.0>}
| 23 | flush().
Shell got {counter,0}
ok
```

I put `io:format("DebugInfo:~p~n", [Sum])` as the first expression in `loop`. Result is:

```
12> Pid ! {code_switch, self()}.
DebugInfo:3
{code_switch,<0.33.0>}
DebugInfo:0
13> flush().
Shell got {switch,3}
Shell got {switched,3}
ok
```

**EDIT:** I found that when I spawn the process via `spawn/3`, aka `spawn(counter, start, []).`, this works. When I spawn the process via `spawn/1`, aka `spawn(fun counter:start/0)`, this doesn't 
work. Is this expected behavior? What am I missing?

[Documentation](http://erldocs.com/current/erts/erlang.html?i=0&search=spawn/1#spawn/1) states for `spawn/1`:

> Returns the process identifier of a new process started by the application of Fun to the empty list []. Otherwise works like spawn/3.

**EDIT:** .... Aaaand after trying to replicate this on an Ubuntu virtual machine (where it didn't happen), I am now also unable to reproduce this (and will test my memory for corruption now..)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the behavior that I am seeing when testing your program:

```
25> LPid ! {counter, self()}.
{counter,<0.39.0>}
26> flush().
Shell got {counter,6}
ok
27> c(counter).
{ok,counter}
28> LPid ! {counter, self()}.
{counter,<0.39.0>}
29> flush().                 
Shell got {counter,6}
ok
30> LPid ! {increment, 2}.
{increment,2}
31> LPid ! {counter, self()}.
{counter,<0.39.0>}
32> flush().                 
Shell got {counter,8}
ok
33> LPid ! {code_switch, self()}.
{code_switch,<0.39.0>}
34> flush().                     
Shell got {switch,8}
Shell got {switched,8}
ok
35> LPid ! {counter, self()}.    
{counter,<0.39.0>}
36> flush().                 
Shell got {counter,8}
ok
```

Can you maybe add some logs like `io:format("DebugInfo:~p~n", [Sum]).` to some of the functions to see what's going on?

Comment: I put the `io:format("DebugInfo:~p~n", [Sum])` as the first expression in `loop`. Result remains. When `loop` is called after the code switch, `Sum` is 0.. (see my post for shell output.)

Comment: To answer your edit, I started the process with spawn like this: `start() -> spawn(fun() -> loop(0) end).`. In the end all mentioned methods are valid, it's probably down to something else rather than to how you started the loop process.